# MySQL Multiple calls to timestamp () in procedure yields the same result

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, procedure

In a procedure I do
1. set a variable called "start" to timestamp ().
2. do something, example insert 1,000,000 rows into a table 
3. set another variable called "stop" to timestamp ();
4. compare "start" to "stop". they are the same, they are the same.

I stopwatch timed the insert it took about a minute.

I read the MySQL manual, which is basically useless.
Real documentation of functions must contain - return type, name of function and parameter (usage and type)  Also side conditions would be helpful.

Comment: There is no `timestamp()` without arguments. Do you mean `current_timestamp()`? That one is explained in documentation properly

Comment: *"I read the MySQL manual, which is basically useless."* i disagree the MySQL manual is pretty usefull actually...  *"Real documentation of functions must contain - return type, name of function and parameter (usage and type)"*  if i look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) i see those things.. Also we don't know what you are talking about post your procedure code atleast..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're volunteers here, and many of us have considerable chunks of our careers invested in the tech you ask about. You'll get better help with phrases like  *I don't understand* than with phrases like *basically useless.*

Comment: Whats the procedure look like?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) says

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for SYSDATE(), which returns the exact time at which it executes.

I guess you use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, because `TIMESTAMP()` requires one or two arguments. The former is a synonym for `NOW()`.

If you want to put time measurement code in a stored procedure or function, `SYSDATE()` is the function for you.